# Who came up with the one-third rule?

Tags: architecture, refactoring

I remember hearing about a year ago about the "one-third rule", which says that if you have to change more than 1/3 of a program you're better off starting from scratch.

Googling around, however, I can't find any references to this rule of thumb, let alone any evidence (even anecdotal), to support it.

Has anyone else heard of this rule and know where it comes from, or did I dream it up myself?

Answer (score 1):

I've never heard of the 1/3rd rule but there have been a number of good discussions along these lines:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6268/when-is-a-big-rewrite-the-answer

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6255/have-you-ever-been-involved-in-a-big-rewrite

And of course one of the more famous posts on this subject:

http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000069.html